# How to convert mongoengine objects to json response

Tags: mongoengine, flask-mongoengine, restframeworkmongoengine

I want to use mongoengine with Flask.

```
from mongoengine import *
connect('db_test', port=27017)

class Client(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True, max_length=200,unique=True)
    tel_nummer = StringField(required=True)
    age = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)

@app.route('/api/clients', methods=['GET'])
def get_clients():
    all_clients=Client.objects.all()
    return jsonify(result=all_clients.to_json())
```

The output is:

```
result  "[{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5cdb1ed17218d7a0b5218832\"}, \"name\": \"Tom\", \"telnummer\": \"34634534\", \"age\": \"34534534\",}]"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Client.objects.all().to_json()` is already returning a json, you shouldn't jsonify it again